# How to get Handsontable data on html button click

Tags: c#, jquery, handsontable

I want to get handsontable data on button click. for this, I'm calling the buttonSave function. But on var JSON I'm getting an error as $container.data is not a function. Where I'm doing wrong?

Code is as below:

```
function buttonSave() {
    var $container = document.getElementById("divadhoc");
    var json = $container.data('handsontable').getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data`  is a jquery function but container is no jquery object. Use `$('#divadhoc')` to create the jquery object.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the help. it worked. but now it's saying "Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined".

Comment: `getData()` is a method of the Handsontable object: `var ht = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example1'), options); ht.getData(...)`

Comment: I tried this, var ht = container.handsontable('getInstance');
        var htContents = ht.getData(); but same error

Comment: Now It's says options is not defined.

Comment: should I put something else in the place of options?